# Processing Presto ResultSet in Java: 'SQLException: Not on a valid row'

Tags: docker, testng, integration-testing, resultset, presto

My [**`Presto` *plugin***](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/develop.html) has two components:

- An [`EventListener`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/develop/event-listener.html) that *logs stats* of queries made to Presto
- Some [`UDF`s](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/develop/functions.html) for *hashing* (`MD5`, `SHA1`) *common datatypes* (`varchar`, `long`) and returning result as `varchar`

---

I've already done:

- *Integration-test* (`mvn verify`) of query-logging component
- *Unit-test* of hashing UDFs

---

In integration test of UDF component, I'm tyring to assert value returned by my UDF by firing a query

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(PRESTO_URL, PRESTO_USER, PRESTO_PASSWORD);
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT SHA1(9223372036854775807) AS hash");
assertEquals("458B642B137E2C76E0B746C6FA43E64C3D4C47F1", resultSet.getString("hash"));
```

This gives following *stack-trace* ([`PrestoResultSet.checkValidRow`](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/blob/master/presto-jdbc/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/jdbc/PrestoResultSet.java#L1659))

*NOTE: `ExtendedHashFunctionsTestIT.java:39` line is the one containing `resultSet.getString(..)`*

> ```
> java.sql.SQLException: Not on a valid row
>     at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoResultSet.checkValidRow(PrestoResultSet.java:1658)
>     at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoResultSet.column(PrestoResultSet.java:1690)
>     at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoResultSet.getString(PrestoResultSet.java:370)
>     at com.company.plugin.it.udfs.scalar.hash.ExtendedHashFunctionsTestIT.testBody(ExtendedHashFunctionsTestIT.java:39)
>     at com.company.plugin.it.AbstractIntegrationTest.test(AbstractIntegrationTest.java:77)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>     at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
>     at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
>     at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1191)
>     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1116)
>     at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1024)
>     at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:62)
>     at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:141)
>     at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:180)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:350)
>     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1021)
> ```

---

I'm perplexed because error occurs only when I try to access `ResultSet`; commenting out the `assertEquals(..)` statement lets the test run successfully.

What's even more disturbing is that stack-trace is same for virtually any query:

- `SELECT 'some_string' AS some_alias`
- `SHOW SCHEMAS`

---

I'm using [*Spotify*'s `dockerfile-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin) for the tests. I've put up relevant files in [this `GitHub Gist`](https://gist.github.com/y2k-shubham/5a143165b7355560b8c92164b198521b)

- `ExtendedHashFunctionsTestIT.java` (*simplified* integration-test file)
- `pom.xml`
- `Dockerfile`

Comment: I bet the https://groups.google.com/d/forum/presto-users is a better place for this kind of questions.
Also, for a unit test you don't need JDBC, see for example `TestArrayFunctions` in Presto code base.

Comment: As suggested by **@PiotrFindeisen**, I've posted [the query](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/presto-users/RTJNh7JZSxY) to *Presto-Users Google Group*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It laments me to think that the mistake that ate up my 2 days was this

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(PRESTO_URL, PRESTO_USER, PRESTO_PASSWORD);
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT SHA1(9223372036854775807) AS hash");
resultSet.next();
assertEquals("458B642B137E2C76E0B746C6FA43E64C3D4C47F1", resultSet.getString("hash"));
```

That 4th line: I had missed `resultSet.next()` prior to `resultSet.getString(..)` :-(